# Service Fabric Stateful services with single DB Persistance service

Tags: azure, architecture, azure-service-fabric

I'm about to start a project that requires very fast response times and high availability, i have done a few service fabric projects before so i'm feeling pretty confident about that.

I'm currently leaning towards a specific design, based on stateful content services as main datasource with a single data persistance service saving to a database of some sort.

Read operations are done by web-api
Write operations are done by Azure service bus communication with Rebus as handler.

**Content services**

- The content services are stateful services which on commit sends a message to the persistance service with the object saved in the reliable dictionary, serialized as json.
- The content services them selves will be responsible for json deserialization in the event that they need to restore the data.
- Restore scenarios could be when the entire dictionary for some reason is lost or when a reset message is put on the bus.

**Persistance service**

- Recieves a message from the bus and stores the included entity, to a data store (Not yet decided, maybe table storage).
- Serves an entire repository of data when a service need to reload data.
- Only concerns itself with storing and retrieving data, no integrity checks

I'm really unsure about whether this is a feasible way of designing a system, that also has a high amount of user data.

what are your thoughts on this design?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Try it and let us know!

Comment: The question really was, if any of you had tried something similar or had any concerns about this design. My main concern is that there really isn't a way to validate the data in the reliable dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up pursuing this solution and it works quite well and performs very well but it needs extensive testing in order to make sure that everything works as expected.